# Parallel algorithm to make three-layered independent operations with nontrivial indexing vectorizable using icc

Tags: c++, intel, icc, avx512, auto-vectorization

The current example shows an execution of N=10 independent operations inside a three-layered loop, but unfortunately the intel compiler autovectorization computes the cost at loop level, and when successfull at the innermost level it refuses to consider the vectorization of the two 'external' loops.

A solution would be to express the same with only one loop, where 'if-else' conditions are allowed but perhaps not encouraged.

The indexing covers a subset of the total possible combinations, if someone knows the formal name of it it would be nice.

A working minimal example for L=5 (i.e. 10 possible combinations) follows.
The production-code makes heavy use of the case with L=6, which has 20 operations that are performed ~100k times (i.e. for different arrays of length 6).

Note: auto-vectorization of the innermost loop has been tested without the prints using `std::cout` at each iteration :-)

Note: for curiosity, the (current) strategy of precomputing the elements (with only the inner loop vectorized, intel report showing "estimated potential speedup: 1.8") as opposed to computing them on the fly only when needed is making the section 12% slower.

```
#include <iostream>

int vectorizable_function(int &A, int &B, int &C) { return A + B - C; }


void populate_combinations(int *container, int L, int *data){

    // Intel vectorization report provides feedback
    // 
    //

    int counter=0;
    for (int i=0; i<L-2; i++){
        for (int j=i+1; j<L-1; j++){
            for (int k=j+1; k<L; k++){
                // std::cout << "i,j,k are " << i << " " << j << " " << k << '\n';
                container[counter] = vectorizable_function( data[i], data[j], data[k] );
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout << "counter was " << counter << std::endl;
}


// Function we want to populate with the parallelizable algorithm
//
void vectorizable_populate_combinationsL5(int * container, int *data){
    #pragma vector always
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
        // Smart algorithm goes here?
    }
}

int main(){

    const int L = 5;

    const int TOTALNCOMBINATIONS = 10;
    int combinations[10];

    int data[5] = {5,6,8,12,3};

    populate_combinations(combinations, L, data);

    std::cout << "Results are:\n";
    for (int i=0; i<TOTALNCOMBINATIONS; i++) std::cout << combinations[i] << std::endl;

}
```

Responding to a comment:

> Is your real function also separable the way this one is, where you
> can compute data[i] + data[j] and reuse it for all data[k]? Also
> commutative between i and j since they're both getting added, only the
> k element is getting subtracted. Although that probably doesn't
> matter, since j runs from [i+1 .. L).

The real function is shown in the following fragment:

```
double dxAll[18]; // declared and populated long before it's needed

int counter = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<4; i++){
      for (int j=i+1; j<5; j++){
        for (int k=j+1; k<6; k++){
              denomAll[counter] = dxAll[i]*dxAll[6 + j]*dxAll[12 + k] +
                dxAll[6 + i]*dxAll[12 + j]*dxAll[k] +
                dxAll[12 + i]*dxAll[j]*dxAll[6 + k] -
                dxAll[i]*dxAll[12 + j]*dxAll[6 + k] -
                dxAll[6 + i]*dxAll[j]*dxAll[12 + k] -
                dxAll[12 + i]*dxAll[6 + j]*dxAll[k];
      counter++;
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Is your real function also separable the way this one is, where you can compute `data[i] + data[j]` and reuse it for all `data[k]`?  Also commutative between `i` and `j` since they're both getting added, only the `k` element is getting subtracted.  Although that probably doesn't matter, since `j` runs from `[i+1 .. L)`.

Comment: I suspect with AVX-512, you could *manually* vectorize this with a couple shuffles and a masked store, after loading a vector that contains all 5 `int32_t` elements.  (With a masked load if you can't safely read past the end of the array or want to grab some zeros.)  But I doubt a compiler would invent that shuffle for you.  IDK, clang might.  (With 20 outputs for your real use-case, you'd need two vectors to hold all the output elements, so maybe twice as much work at worst, if you can't reuse some earlier temporaries.)

Comment: Are you only interested in having ICC auto-vectorize this, or would you want a manually-vectorized shuffle?  One simple general strategy would be broadcast-loads in the outer loops, and a normal load in the inner.  For small L, a specific manual strategy would be much better.

Comment: Manually vectorized would be a valid answer, thanks.

Comment: Oh, and these are 64-bit `double` elements, not integer, so a `__m512d` vector can only hold 8 at a time!  ICC will pretend FP math is associative by default; I assume you're wanting to do the same, and contract to FMA when possible.  At least we have the real picture now, so manual vectorization could be looked at.

Comment: Yep, assuming associativity and calling FMA is O.K. Sorry for the disappointment, when wrote the toy example I thought the emphasis was O.K. in some "smart 1D indexing". Sorry!

Comment: @PeterCordes were you able to manually vectorize  it? That would be super!

Comment: I haven't tried; it's a lot of elements to keep track of where they need to get shuffled to, and seems like a *very* specific problem of little benefit to other future readers since it would be different for other `L`.  It should still be possible to get a major speedup, but probably a few hours to a day to really think through the possibilities for what shuffles to use, unless it turns out to be easier (simpler pattern) than I'm expecting to get near-optimal code.  If nobody posts an answer within a few days, consider hiring an expert if have a budget for that.  (I do freelance, BTW.)

Answer (score 3):

Write all your combinations on paper:

```
0 1 2
0 1 3
0 1 4
0 2 3
0 2 4
0 3 4
1 2 3
1 2 4
1 3 4
2 3 4
```

Note that there are 10 rows with 3 numbers, 30 numbers total. You need 30 bytes to encode that.

```
void vectorizable_populate_combinationsL5(int *__restrict container, int *__restrict ){
    static const uint8_t index_i[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2};
    static const uint8_t index_j[] = {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3};
    static const uint8_t index_k[] = {2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4};

    #pragma vector always
    for (int counter = 0; counter < 10; counter++)
    {
        int i = index_i[counter];
        int j = index_j[counter];
        int k = index_k[counter];
        container[i] = vectorizable_function(data[i], data[j], data[k]);
    }
}
```

Using `__restrict` pointers will let the compiler know that there's no aliasing between input and output, letting it reuse temporaries in registers and otherwise do [CSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_subexpression_elimination) (Common subexpression elimination).

This does fully unroll to scalar add instructions with clang/LLVM (including the ICX OneAPI compiler which is based on LLVM).

But with the classic ICC, it not only unrolls, it also actually *vectorizes*.  (https://godbolt.org/z/1f7rj1jKc).  But unfortunately, to twice as many instructions than LLVM's scalar version, including 3x gather and 1x scatter (with `-march=skylake-avx512`)!  However, it might not need many more instructions for a more complex `vectorizable_function` with the same input data pattern.

(Without `__restrict`, ICC doesn't vectorize, and does 2 loads + a store for every output element, not reusing loads.)

Comment: And the idea is that the compiler fully unrolls this loop, doing constant propagation to eliminate the actual arrays?  Then it can see the direct computation of each output element, and hopefully invents a SIMD shuffle?

Comment: I hope so! I have little experience with automatic vectorization; no idea how smart it is nowadays. Anyway, even if it uses "gather" instructions, it should be better than 3 nested loops.

Comment: Tested it over the actual code and it vectorizes w/ `scalar cost: 98`, `vector cost: 82.5` and Estimated Potential Speedup `1.180`. It reduces the overhead of precomputing data, but computing on the fly (without vectorization) is still a better strategy.